# Problem at building a ble scanner in Android Studio with cordova, using the Cordova-bluetoothle-plugin

Tags: javascript, android-studio, cordova, bluetooth-lowenergy

At the moment i'm programming an application to config a gateway-device.
For this, i use android studio with cordova and the cordova-bluetoothle-plugin for JavaScript.

At first i would like to build a simple BLE-Scanner which searches for BLE-Devices and insert they in a table.

Every time i scan for devices, i get this error in the logcat of Android Studio:

```
2023-11-29 14:32:19.511  7022-7022  chromium                io.cordova.hellocordova              I  [INFO:CONSOLE(22)] "Uncaught ReferenceError: bluetoothle is not defined", source: https://localhost/js/index.js (22)
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/index.css">
    <title>GateWay-Configuration</title>
    <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="js/device.js"></script>-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="plugins/cordova-plugin-bluetoothle/www/bluetoothle.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!--<script>window.onload = scanForDevices;</script>-->
<div id="header">
    <text id="headline">GateWay-Configuration</text>
    <text id="secHeadline">Device-List</text>
</div>
<div id="content">
    <!--<text id="status">Not searching</text>
        <table id="DeviceTable">
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>-->
    <table border="1">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Number</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Address</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="deviceTableBody">
        <!-- Device entries will be added here -->
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
<button type="button" id="buttonAtBottom" onclick = "onDeviceReady()">Scan for Devices</button>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is my JS:

```
function onDeviceReady() {
    document.getElementById('deviceTableBody').innerHTML = '<tr><td colspan="3">Searching for devices...</td></tr>';
    findDevices();
}

function displayDevices(devices) {
    var tableBody = document.getElementById('deviceTableBody');
    tableBody.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing entries

    if (devices.length > 0) {
        for (var i = 0; i < devices.length; i++) {
            var device = devices[i];
            var row = `<tr><td>${device.nr}</td><td>${device.name}</td><td>${device.address}</td></tr>`;
            tableBody.innerHTML += row;
        }
    } else {
        tableBody.innerHTML = '<tr><td colspan="3">No devices found</td></tr>';
    }
}

function findDevices() {
    bluetoothle.startScan({ services: [] }, function (result) {
        if (result.status === 'scanResult') {
            displayDevices(result.scanRecord);
        } else if (result.status === 'scanStarted') {
            // Scanning started
        } else if (result.status === 'scanStopped') {
            // Scanning stopped
        }
    }, function (error) {
        console.error("Error during Bluetooth scan: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });

    setTimeout(stopScan, 5000); // Stop scanning after 5 seconds (adjust as needed)
}

function stopScan() {
    bluetoothle.stopScan(function (result) {
        // Scanning stopped
    }, function (error) {
        console.error("Error stopping Bluetooth scan: " + JSON.stringify(error));
    });
}
```

I already have tried to reinstall the plugin by using the comands:

```
$ cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-bluetoothle
$ cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-bluetoothle
```

The plugins seems to be install successfully:

```
cordova plugin ls
cordova-plugin-bluetoothle 6.7.4 "Bluetooth LE"
```

And i have already tried to reinstall the plattform by using the commands:

```
$ cordova platform rm android
$ cordova platform add android
```

The error is still the same

Does someone has an idea how i can fix this error?